# Manually Disable Wifi before suspend

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 18.10, atheros

i'm running Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome - Suspend to Ram isn't working. my syslog told me that **wpa_supllicant** refuses to freeze. I already tried a couple fixes but none are working. Most of them are different variations of [this](https://medium.com/@foxoman/fix-wifi-not-working-after-suspend-ubuntu-682d04e4bdbd). I Also tried using a different Firmware version as stated [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln309066/killer-wireless-firmware-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems?lang=en). Although this is a bit over the top since wifi is working fine and my idea is to run a script ,when hitting the suspend button, that turns the wifi off, before the actual suspend action takes place.

Suspend to Ram is working if i disable wifi manually before suspending. Is there a way to automate it?

Wireless Chipset:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 20
       serial: c0:38:96:2f:a8:1f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-13-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1
```

**Update #1:** as @GAD3R pointed out a Script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep will do the trick. However it doesn't seem to work. I created the Script

> killwpa

in

> /lib/systemd/system-sleep

and made it executable using

> sudo chmod +x

I still cant suspend with Wifi on here's the output of my **syslog**:

```
Freezing user space processes ... 
Freezing of tasks failed after 20.002 seconds (9 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
wpa_supplicant  D    0  1013      1 0x00000004
```

**Update 2:** I modified the Script to unload the driver using `modprobe` and stopping the network manager - still freezing.

**Script:**

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then

modprobe -rv ath10k_pci
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service 

elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then

modprobe -v  ath10k_pci
systemctl start NetworkManager.service

fi
```

**syslog ouput:**

```
Feb  1 09:13:25 aaron-GACK kernel: [ 1350.265251] Freezing user space processes ... 
Feb  1 09:13:25 aaron-GACK kernel: [ 1370.272019] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.006 seconds (3 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Feb  1 09:13:25 aaron-GACK kernel: [ 1370.274617] wpa_supplicant  D    0  1036      1 0x00000004
```

**Update 3:**
I tried simplifying it and use a single script to unload the driver and kill wpa as recommended by GAD3R:

```
!/bin/bash
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
modprobe -rv ath10k_pci
/usr/bin/pkill wpa_supplicant
fi
```

**Holy Moly - it worked!** Back after suspending and Wifi is back on as well.

**Update 4:**
Nevermind. Tried Suspending again after the successful try...aaaand freeze again. 
**Syslog:**

```
Feb  1 09:27:30 aaron-GACK kernel: [  421.558759] Freezing user space processes ... 
Feb  1 09:27:30 aaron-GACK kernel: [  441.561752] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.002 seconds (10 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Feb  1 09:27:30 aaron-GACK kernel: [  441.564343] wpa_supplicant  D    0  1082      1 0x00000004
```

Comment: " I already tried a couple fixes but none are working." the answer you will get are likely any one of those fixes so please list them to avoid others wasting your and their time ;) Mind that there is a setting to "turn of wifi to save power" in the "power" settings  that probably does what you want

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind! Added them and clarified what i wanted to do. The 'power off to save power' option just turns off the wifi - which should be the same as clicking it in the panel and turning it off. Which *does* work but isn't optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do much the same before suspend and tried your scripts, both forms.  Syslog showed format errors and the script failing. Is systemd picky about script format?

This worked for me, having tested manually that just unloading the driver allowed successful suspending.

```
!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
pre/*)
modprobe -rv ath10k_pci
;;
post/*)
modprobe -v  ath10k_pci
;;
esac
```